# How to do a simple Count in Linq?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ado.net, linq-to-entities

I wanted to do a paging style table, but NeerDinner example fetches the entire data into a `PaggingList` type, and I have more than 10 000 rows to be fetched, so I skipped that part.

so I come up with this query

```
var r = (from p in db.Prizes
            join c in db.Calendars on p.calendar_id equals c.calendar_id
            join ch in db.Challenges on c.calendar_id equals ch.calendar_id
            join ca in db.ChallengeAnswers on ch.challenge_id equals ca.challenge_id
            join cr in db.ChallengeResponses on ca.challenge_answer_id equals cr.challenge_answer_id

            where
                p.prize_id.Equals(prizeId)
                && ch.day >= p.from_day && ch.day <= p.to_day
                && ca.correct.Equals(true)
                && ch.day.Equals(day)

            orderby cr.Subscribers.name

            select new PossibleWinner()
            {
                Name = cr.Subscribers.name,
                Email = cr.Subscribers.email,
                SubscriberId = cr.subscriber_id,
                ChallengeDay = ch.day,
                Question = ch.question,
                Answer = ca.answer
            })
        .Skip(size * page)
        .Take(size);
```

Problem is, **how can I get the total number of results** before the `Take` part?

I was thinking of:

```
var t = (from p in db.JK_Prizes
            join c in db.JK_Calendars on p.calendar_id equals c.calendar_id
            join ch in db.JK_Challenges on c.calendar_id equals ch.calendar_id
            join ca in db.JK_ChallengeAnswers on ch.challenge_id equals ca.challenge_id
            join cr in db.JK_ChallengeResponses on ca.challenge_answer_id equals cr.challenge_answer_id

            where
                p.prize_id.Equals(prizeId)
                && ch.day >= p.from_day && ch.day <= p.to_day
                && ca.correct.Equals(true)
                && ch.day.Equals(day)

            select cr.subscriber_id)
        .Count();
```

but that will do the query all over again...

anyone has suggestions on how can I **do this effectively** ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ: Paging tecnique, using take and skip but need total records also - how to implement this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275935/linq-paging-tecnique-using-take-and-skip-but-need-total-records-also-how-to-i)

Comment: @Hansmukh I'm not asking how to do paging... I'm asking how to `Count` :)

Comment: What about the answer on this page ? Linq Paging - How to incorporate total record count http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553167/linq-paging-how-to-incorporate-total-record-count

Comment: =) i know.one thing i wanna point here, as you already said that you have thousands of records then it will be nice practice to do that paging thing at database end rather then doing that on entities level =) Performance is always matters =)

Comment: @Fasih Hansmukh thanks! just when I read your comment head made a click... SP always :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you take a query as such:

```
var qry = (from x in y
           select x).Count();
```

...LINQ to SQL will be clever enough to make this a `SELECT COUNT` query, which is potentially rather efficient (efficiency will depend more on the conditions in the query). Bottom line is that the count operation happens in the database, not in LINQ code.

Comment: ahhh, I was missing the "clever enough" part :)

Answer (score 0):

Writing my old comments :Well i was facing the same issue some time back and then i came up with LINQ to SP =). Make an SP and drop that into your entities and use it.you can get write Sp according to your need like pulling total record column too. It is more easy and fast as compare to that whet you are using wright now.

Answer (score 0):

You can put count for query logic as well as, see the sample as below:

```
 public int GetTotalCountForAllEmployeesByReportsTo(int? reportsTo, string orderBy = default(string), int startRowIndex = default(int), int maximumRows = default(int))
        {
            //Validate Input
            if (reportsTo.IsEmpty())
                return GetTotalCountForAllEmployees(orderBy, startRowIndex, maximumRows);

            return _DatabaseContext.Employees.Count(employee => reportsTo == null ? employee.ReportsTo == null : employee.ReportsTo == reportsTo);
        }
```